# How to compare 2 data frame and convert into list

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I am trying to find a match in any columns in df1 that match any columns in df2 and return the Id number and the matching values and values. Then I would like to Convert to a list.

For example

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 cols = ['Num1','Num2','Num3','Num4','Num5','Num6']

 df1 = pd.DataFrame([[2,4,6,8,9,10],[10,13,15,17,26,44],[27,28,34,37,37,40]],
                     columns=cols)

 df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,2,4,5,6,8],
               [2,5,6,20,22,23,34],
               [3,8,12,13,34,45,46],
               [4,9,10,14,29,32,33],
               [5,1,22,13,23,33,35],
               [6,1,6,7,8,9,10],
               [7,0,2,3,5,6,8]], 
               columns = ['Id', 'Num1','Num2','Num3','Num4','Num5','Num6'])
```

Convert into list.
I would like my results to be like this.

```
   result = [[1,1,2,2,4,4,5,6,6,8,8], [2,5,6,6,20,22,23,34],
[3,8,8,12,13,34,45,46],[4,9,9,10,10,14,29,32,33],[6,1,6,6,7,8,8,9,9,10,10],
[7,0,2,2,3,5,6,6,8,8]], [[3,8,12,13,13,34,45,46],[5,1,22,13,13,23,33,35],
[6,1,6,7,8,9,10,10]],[[2,5,6,20,22,23,34],[3,8,12,13,34,34,45,46]]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how results is generated in your question? I don't quite understand the logic that generates it.